# Why is map not working but foreach is?

Tags: google-maps, dart, angular-dart

This `forEach` works just fine

```
var newMarkers = new List<Marker>();
providers.forEach((p) {
  var marker = markerFrom(p);
  newMarkers.add(marker);
  print("got one");
});

_markers = newMarkers;
```

but this `map` doesn't ever get called when placed in the exact same place as the `forEach`:

```
_markers = providers.map((p) => markerFrom(p));
```

Additionally, this is the `markerFrom` method:

```
  Marker markerFrom(FoodProvider provider) {
  var marker = new Marker(new MarkerOptions()
    ..map = _map
    ..position = new LatLng(provider.latitude, provider.longitude)
    ..title = provider.name
    ..icon = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
  );

  var infoWindow = new InfoWindow(new InfoWindowOptions()..content = marker.title);

  marker.onClick.listen((e) {
    infoWindow.open(_map, marker);
  });

  return marker;
}
```

Comment: do you have any error message ? an careful, if you want to manipulate a `List<Marker>`, `map` will produce an `Iterable`, so you have to do `_markers = providers.map((p) => markerFrom(p)).toList();`, but it depends of what you want to do with `_markers`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `map` function on `Iterable` is *lazy*. It just creates a wrapper around the original `Iterable`, but it doesn't actually do anything until you start iterating.

That's a *good thing*, even if it can be surprising if you are used to an eager `map` function from other languages. It means that you can combine operations on iterables like:

```dart
listOfStrings
    .map((x) => complicatedOperationOnString(x))
    .take(2)
    .forEach(print);
```

This only does the complicated operation on the first two strings.

If you want a list of the markers, you need to call `toList` after the `map`:

```dart
_markers = providers.map(markerFrom).toList();
```

In general, you should be very careful when the function passed to `map` has side-effects that you want to only happen once. If you iterate the result of `map` more than once, that effect will happen each time, so if you did:

```dart
_markers = providers.map(markerFrom);
int count = _markers.length;
_markers.forEach((marker) { doSomething(marker); });
```

you would *risk* the side effects happening twice, once for `length` and once for `forEach`, which both iterate `_markers`.
It doesn't always happen (some iterables know their `length` without actually iterating), but it is always a risk. In those cases, either use `forEach` if the side-effect is the only thing you are after, or do an immediate `toList` to force all the operations, and then only look at the resulting list after that.

Comment: Is there any way to just do a normal map? This behaviour is very inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: The `map` operation in Dart is always lazy, as is `where` and all other members of `Iterable`. As such, it's internally consistent. If you want to eagerly create a new list, all you have to do is follow the `map` operation with `.toList()`: `_markers = providers.map(markerFrom).toList();` or `_markers = [...providers.map(markerFrom)]`. If you want an alternative, I'd use is the list literal iteration: `[for (var p in providers) markerFrom(p)]`. It's not as short, but perhaps more readable.

Comment: This doesn't work with async functions in the map callback. I think perhaps it would need to be used in combination with Future.wait or similar.