# Snapshot code inside StreamBuilder does not get executed when receiving data from Firebase FireCloud in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm trying to get description text from Firecloud database and use them in 3 differnt widgets, add those widget to a list and then pass that list in a `ListView`.
I executed the following code for this purpose inside `StreamBuilder`:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('humansOfLpc').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot){
                if(!snapshot.hasData){
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('Loading...'),
                  );
                }
                print('outside title and desc widget');
                List<TitleAndDescription> titleAndDescriptions=[
                ];
                snapshot.data.docs.map((document){
                    final about = document.data()["about"];
                    final aftercampusProgress =document.data()["afterCampusPlacement"];
                    final incampusPlacement = document.data()["incampusProgress"];
                    print('inside snapshots');
                    print(about);
                    final aboutDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'About',
                      description: about,
                    );
                    final incampusProgressDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'In-Campus Progress',
                      description: incampusProgress,
                    );
                    final afterCampusPlacementDesc=TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'After Campus Placements',
                      description: afterCampusPlacement,
                    );
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(aboutDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(incampusProgressDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(afterCampusPlacementDesc);

                });

                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: titleAndDescriptions,
                  ),
                );

              },
            ),
```

The main problem here I am facing is that its not reading the following code:

```dart
snapshot.data.docs.map((document){
                    final about = document.data()["about"];
                    final aftercampusProgress =document.data()["afterCampusPlacement"];
                    final incampusPlacement = document.data()["incampusProgress"];
                    print('inside snapshots');
                    print(about);
                    final aboutDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'About',
                      description: about,
                    );
                    final incampusProgressDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'In-Campus Progress',
                      description: incampusProgress,
                    );
                    final afterCampusPlacementDesc=TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'After Campus Placements',
                      description: afterCampusPlacement,
                    );
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(aboutDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(incampusProgressDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(afterCampusPlacementDesc);

                });
```

I can say this since the console is printing `'outside title and desc widget'` but not printing `'inside snapshots'`.
Because of this my `titleAndDescriptions` list is empty and I am not getting the 3 widgets as well as data on my UI. Pls tell what am I doing wrong and what alternative do I have instead ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `forEach` instead of `map`

```
snapshot.data.docs.forEach((document){
                    final about = document.data()["about"];
                    final aftercampusProgress =document.data()["afterCampusPlacement"];
                    final incampusPlacement = document.data()["incampusProgress"];
                    print('inside snapshots');
                    print(about);
                    final aboutDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'About',
                      description: about,
                    );
                    final incampusProgressDesc = TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'In-Campus Progress',
                      description: incampusProgress,
                    );
                    final afterCampusPlacementDesc=TitleAndDescription(
                      title: 'After Campus Placements',
                      description: afterCampusPlacement,
                    );
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(aboutDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(incampusProgressDesc);
                    titleAndDescriptions.add(afterCampusPlacementDesc);

                });
```

See [Why map doesn't work but forEach does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299842/why-is-map-not-working-but-foreach-is) here.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me. For some unknown reason map doesn't work, but foreach does!