# Pulling data from QuerySnapshot in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I need to populate a DropdownButton from a document in Firestore. I can retrieve the data. When I look into the snapshot.data I see 2 records which is what I expect to see. In the code below, everything works fine as long as I comment out the code snippet as you can see.

```
    Container(
                      child: StreamBuilder(
                          //stream: _firestoreService.getAgency(),
                          stream: _db.collection('agency').snapshots(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                              return Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            } else {
                              //var length = snapshot.data.docs.length;
                              //print('length: ' + length);
                              return new DropdownButton<String>(
                                hint: new Text("Select Agency"),
                                value: _currentAgency,
    /*  <<<< The code below is where I am having problems
                                //onChanged: changedDropDownState,
                                **items: snapshot.data.docs.map((Map map) {
                                  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: map["name"].toString(),
                                    child: new Text(
                                    map["name"],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),**
*/
                              );
                            }
                            ;
                          }),
                    ),
```

When I uncomment the code and run the app I get this error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#d9273):
type '(Map<dynamic, dynamic>) => DropdownMenuItem<String>' is not a subtype of type '(QueryDocumentSnapshot) => dynamic' of 'f'
```

What I want to accomplish is to populate the value: attribute with the document ID but I don't see it in snapshot.data. The other thing I want to do is populate child: attribute with some of the values from the snapshot.data.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here

```
items: snapshot.data.docs.map(( ISSUE HERE===>Map map) {
  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: map["name"].toString(),
  child: new Text(
  map["name"],
     ),
   );
 }).toList(),
```

The value for `docs` is `QueryDocumentSnapshot` and not type `Map` that is why you got the error message.

Instead, change it to this.

```
items: snapshot.data.docs.map((documentSnapshot) {
  return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
  value: documentSnapshot["name"].toString(),
  child: new Text(
  documentSnapshot["name"],
     ),
   );
 }).toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that says to use .forEach instead of map ([Snapshot code inside StreamBuilder does not get executed when receiving data from Firebase FireCloud in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63748354/snapshot-code-inside-streambuilder-does-not-get-executed-when-receiving-data-fro)).

This gets rid of the error but the DropdownButton is static and won't drop down or let me click on it. Here is my new code for the DropdownButton:

```
return new DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: new Text("Select Agency"),
                            value: _currentAgency,
                            //onChanged: changedDropDownState,
                            items: snapshot.data.docs.forEach((document) {
                              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: document.data()['name'],
                                child: new Text(document.data()['name']),
                              );
                            }),
                          );
```

The data is there and I can see it when I debug. I want to get the documentId as well but I don't see that in the debugger.

How do I get the DropdownButton to be active and how do I add the documentId to the value: attribute?